# SSRS Charts: Filter Top10 - or TopX if X categories already make up 99% of the total?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I show sum(x) in a bar chart and did set it up to display only the top 10 categories - those 10 where the sum of x is the highest.

So far so good. Sometimes, however, two or three categories make up 99% of the total. In these cases I would like to hide the other 7 categories that have .0x% each since this is not valuable in the chart.

I somehow need to change the Top-10 to Top-SomethingElse based on the % of the total a category represents.

What I am looking for is basically:
Show me the top categories that represent, say 1% or more, of the total - but not more than 10 of them.

How could I accomplish that?

Thank You in advance for your answers!

Comment: Do you want to put the logic in a stored procedure, inline query, dataset filters?

Comment: It has to be a filter on the chart because the dataset is used in other places within the report and should not be filtered there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking how to do this without modifying the sql. If that is the case then simply select the group where the SUM(x) is aggregated. Then left click and select the "Group Properties..." popup menu item. Select the "Filter" list view item from the list view on the left side of the dialog. In the filters screen enter a filter that specifies that X must be >= 1.

If you would like to do this in sql then I would envision a query similar to:

```
    SELECT TOP(10)
       SumOfX
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            SumOfX=SUM(SomeTallyField)
        FROM
            SomeTable
        GROUP BY
            SomeGroupField
        HAVING 
            SUM(SomeTallyField) >= 1
    )AS X
    ORDER BY
        SomeTallyField DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, _sum(x)>1_ does not do the trick, regardless of where I filter it. It has to be based on percentage, even if sum(x) = 1,000,000 it should not show if five other categories have sums in the billions...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Filtering on sum(x)>=1 does not work. A quick example shows why: having three bars with sum(x) in the millions and 7 bars with sum(x) between 1 and 10 is one of those cases where I want to hide these 7 bars. They all satisfy sum(x)>1 and would not be hidden by such a simple filter. A percentage of total needs to be used.

As it turns out, it was quite easy after all. I need two filters. The first one I already had in place:

```
Top 10 of sum(x)
```

This limits the total number of bars to 10, even if more than 10 would meet my other criteria. The second filter compares the sum to the dataset total. This was what I didn't get to work earlier because I thought of it too complicated. But it is quite simple:

```
=sum(x)/sum(x,"DataSet1")     >= 0.01
```

This requires a bar to be at least 1% of the total to show up in the chart. In my example from above, those 7 bars would not make it onto the chart, because they represent way less than 1% if the top 3 are already in the millions.